# http rest api - how to load field of respons string to variable

Tags: c#, rest

I'm developing an application which use HTTP REST API .I'm load response to string which looks like this:

```
string report = "<html><head><tittle>JSLEE OC WebSerbice</title></head><body>
<code><h3>JSLEE webService received REST request:</h3>
<p>HttpRequest..............</p>
<p>X: 52 10 28 <p> Y: 32 12 32 </body></html>"
```

I want to load value of X and Y to other variables, how can I do that?

Comment: Usually, a rest API should return content-type in application/json or application/xml, not text/html. Are you own the API? or could you contact the API provider to make sure your request is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are becoming HTTP response from web page.

Use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse response and extract your values

Comment: Regfor, thanks this link is very helpfull no idea why i didnt find it by myself my guess its too early to work :< now i have to dig through docummentation. thx again :))